# How to find out in the log the cause of rebalancing in Kafka streams applications

Tags: apache-kafka-streams

My Kafka streams application keeps rebalancing often and often. I have red several ticket on here, as wellas blogpost about the different solution. E.g. MAX_POLL_INTERVAL_MS  and MAX_POLL_RECORDS.

I have played with them, and I a running with static membership.

At this point I am trying to find out what are the possible cause from the log, so instead  of just guessing and applying those setting, I actually understand and identify the cause.

Hence what I am asking for is what log config do I need to have both on the broker and the stream  application, and what line of log do I need to grep.

I have gone through the log, but without knowing the typical error or warning, or keywords to grep it is near impossible to figure out what's going on especially if both the broker and app are in Debug. It is a lot of logs to go through without knowing what to grep.

Hence, what keywords should I grep for? I will probably add things like -A 20 -B 20 to surround the area.

### Edit

In  my Kafka streams application, I find a lot of those

```
14:46:23.166 [sdc-oxygen-dev-entellect-cbe-builder-resnet-12-StreamThread-1] DEBUG o.a.k.s.p.internals.StreamThread - stream-thread [sdc-oxygen-dev-entellect-cbe-builder-resnet-12-StreamThread-1] Unable to commit as we are in the middle of a rebalance, will try again when it completes.
14:46:23.166 [sdc-oxygen-dev-entellect-cbe-builder-resnet-12-StreamThread-1] DEBUG o.a.k.s.p.internals.StreamThread - stream-thread [sdc-oxygen-dev-entellect-cbe-builder-resnet-12-StreamThread-1] Processing tasks with 2550 iterations.
14:46:23.172 [sdc-oxygen-dev-entellect-cbe-builder-resnet-12-StreamThread-2] DEBUG o.a.k.s.p.internals.StreamThread - stream-thread [sdc-oxygen-dev-entellect-cbe-builder-resnet-12-StreamThread-2] Processed 2886 records with 2886 iterations; invoking punctuators if necessary
14:46:23.172 [sdc-oxygen-dev-entellect-cbe-builder-resnet-12-StreamThread-2] DEBUG o.a.k.s.p.internals.StreamThread - stream-thread [sdc-oxygen-dev-entellect-cbe-builder-resnet-12-StreamThread-2] 0 punctuators ran.
14:46:23.172 [sdc-oxygen-dev-entellect-cbe-builder-resnet-12-StreamThread-2] DEBUG o.a.k.s.p.internals.StreamThread - stream-thread [sdc-oxygen-dev-entellect-cbe-builder-resnet-12-StreamThread-2] Committing all active tasks [10_6, 28_6, 44_6, 14_6, 32_6, 2_6, 18_6, 36_6, 6_6, 24_6, 40_6] and standby tasks [] since 203216ms has elapsed (commit interval is 120000ms)
```

Answer (score 1):

Distributed Stream Processing Systems(DSPs) contain `Scheduler` of types `Static` and `Adaptive` which Maps Application Topology to the Physical Nodes. `Adaptive Scheduler` continuously Monitors the system in order to offload overloaded nodes and vice versa. However, it might be triggered periodically or based on load threshold.

Accordingly, my will guess about your main concerns, it might be set rebalancing the system within specific intervals **OR** system might suffer from a weak node that forces it to rebalance the overall system again and again in order to prevent catastrophic failure.

It's not all the possible reasons. However, the main reasons in most cases.

Comment: Thank for taking the time. However, would you be able to translate it, in kafka, kafka stream jardon, more over, what  indictor in the log can i look at, would really help. How do you find out a weak node for instance ? Are you  talking about a kafka stream instance, or a broker ?

Comment: @MaatDeamon would you please provide a comprehensive logcat, provide a link, to see. and your environment setup is also helpful.

Comment: Hi, I ended figuring part of the problem. I was polling too much record. Changing  max  poll record to a reasonable default made the trick.

Comment: @MaatDeamon was my answer helpful? how can I help you more? as matter of fact I am working on DSPs for my master Thesis.

Comment: In the general sense yet, it did help. But not in the particular kafka things i  needed to figure out. In a sense, it broaden my perspective of investigation. e.g. I checked my kubernetes DNS, and so forth.

Comment: I just opened a new question with some logs, and that is  where i am now. My app is not rebalancing so far, but i still get some of things that were happening when it was re-balancing. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68609656/kafka-streams-intermittent-isdisconnected