# kafka-streams intermittent isDisconnected

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I have an  intermittent issue in my logs.

It seems the heart-thread is  constantly struggling and get

```
Error sending fetch request
org.apache.kafka.common.errors.DisconnectException

Group coordinator xxx is unavailable or invalid due to cause: coordinator unavailable.isDisconnected: true. Rediscovery will be attempted.
```

i already made the heartbeat.interval.ms a bit larger, but this it is still happening.

1. I would like to understand what this can cascade into, in a kafka-streams application configured for static membership. In particular can it lead to re-balance ?
2. I have also increased `request.timeout.ms` shall I  also increase `delivery.timeout.ms`, if so why?
3. I  am trying to understand how things cascade. That  is,  What happen if the heartbeat thread keep trying and then reach `delivery.timeout.ms` ? is that what causes `is unavailable or invalid due to cause: coordinator unavailable.isDisconnected: true` ? What controls  the subsequent  retry after that. Indeed the consumer isnot failing, itrecoves asitultimately discover the coordinator ?

I am a  little and confused about how this can cascade, hence  looking for a way to explain it, and get a handle on it.

Any idea on how to help with this  ?

```
09:48:12.357 [sdc-oxygen-dev-entellect-cbe-builder-resnet-22-StreamThread-2] INFO  o.a.k.s.p.internals.StreamThread - stream-thread [sdc-oxygen-dev-entellect-cbe-builder-resnet-22-StreamThread-2] Processed 70000 total records, ran 0 punctuators, and committed 3 total tasks since the last update
09:48:21.125 [kafka-coordinator-heartbeat-thread | _entellect-cbe-builder-resnet-0] INFO  o.a.k.clients.FetchSessionHandler - [Consumer instanceId=sdc-oxygen-dev-entellect-cbe-builder-resnet-22-1, clientId=sdc-oxygen-dev-entellect-cbe-builder-resnet-22-StreamThread-1-consumer, groupId=_entellect-cbe-builder-resnet-0] Error sending fetch request (sessionId=1490129196, epoch=INITIAL) to node 0:
org.apache.kafka.common.errors.DisconnectException: null
09:48:21.125 [kafka-coordinator-heartbeat-thread | _entellect-cbe-builder-resnet-0] INFO  o.a.k.clients.FetchSessionHandler - [Consumer instanceId=sdc-oxygen-dev-entellect-cbe-builder-resnet-22-1, clientId=sdc-oxygen-dev-entellect-cbe-builder-resnet-22-StreamThread-1-consumer, groupId=_entellect-cbe-builder-resnet-0] Error sending fetch request (sessionId=1666554310, epoch=INITIAL) to node 4:
org.apache.kafka.common.errors.DisconnectException: null
09:48:21.225 [kafka-coordinator-heartbeat-thread | _entellect-cbe-builder-resnet-0] INFO  o.a.k.clients.FetchSessionHandler - [Consumer instanceId=sdc-oxygen-dev-entellect-cbe-builder-resnet-22-1, clientId=sdc-oxygen-dev-entellect-cbe-builder-resnet-22-StreamThread-1-consumer, groupId=_entellect-cbe-builder-resnet-0] Error sending fetch request (sessionId=522549112, epoch=INITIAL) to node 5:
org.apache.kafka.common.errors.DisconnectException: null
09:48:42.711 [kafka-coordinator-heartbeat-thread | _entellect-cbe-builder-resnet-0] INFO  o.a.k.clients.FetchSessionHandler - [Consumer instanceId=sdc-oxygen-dev-entellect-cbe-builder-resnet-22-2, clientId=sdc-oxygen-dev-entellect-cbe-builder-resnet-22-StreamThread-2-consumer, groupId=_entellect-cbe-builder-resnet-0] Error sending fetch request (sessionId=810037183, epoch=INITIAL) to node 2:
org.apache.kafka.common.errors.DisconnectException: null
09:49:23.172 [kafka-coordinator-heartbeat-thread | _entellect-cbe-builder-resnet-0] INFO  o.a.k.clients.FetchSessionHandler - [Consumer instanceId=sdc-oxygen-dev-entellect-cbe-builder-resnet-22-2, clientId=sdc-oxygen-dev-entellect-cbe-builder-resnet-22-StreamThread-2-consumer, groupId=_entellect-cbe-builder-resnet-0] Error sending fetch request (sessionId=810037183, epoch=INITIAL) to node 2:
org.apache.kafka.common.errors.DisconnectException: null
09:50:17.295 [sdc-oxygen-dev-entellect-cbe-builder-resnet-22-StreamThread-2] INFO  o.a.k.s.p.internals.StreamThread - stream-thread [sdc-oxygen-dev-entellect-cbe-builder-resnet-22-StreamThread-2] Processed 42290 total records, ran 0 punctuators, and committed 3 total tasks since the last update
09:52:28.299 [sdc-oxygen-dev-entellect-cbe-builder-resnet-22-StreamThread-2] INFO  o.a.k.s.p.internals.StreamThread - stream-thread [sdc-oxygen-dev-entellect-cbe-builder-resnet-22-StreamThread-2] Processed 60000 total records, ran 0 punctuators, and committed 1 total tasks since the last update
09:54:35.743 [sdc-oxygen-dev-entellect-cbe-builder-resnet-22-StreamThread-2] INFO  o.a.k.s.p.internals.StreamThread - stream-thread [sdc-oxygen-dev-entellect-cbe-builder-resnet-22-StreamThread-2] Processed 60000 total records, ran 0 punctuators, and committed 1 total tasks since the last update
09:55:07.269 [kafka-coordinator-heartbeat-thread | _entellect-cbe-builder-resnet-0] INFO  o.a.k.c.c.i.AbstractCoordinator - [Consumer instanceId=sdc-oxygen-dev-entellect-cbe-builder-resnet-22-1, clientId=sdc-oxygen-dev-entellect-cbe-builder-resnet-22-StreamThread-1-consumer, groupId=_entellect-cbe-builder-resnet-0] Group coordinator sdc-oxygen-dev-cp-kafka-4.sdc-oxygen-dev-cp-kafka-headless.sdc-oxygen-dev:9092 (id: 2147483643 rack: null) is unavailable or invalid due to cause: coordinator unavailable.isDisconnected: true. Rediscovery will be attempted.
09:55:07.371 [kafka-coordinator-heartbeat-thread | _entellect-cbe-builder-resnet-0] INFO  o.a.k.c.c.i.AbstractCoordinator - [Consumer instanceId=sdc-oxygen-dev-entellect-cbe-builder-resnet-22-1, clientId=sdc-oxygen-dev-entellect-cbe-builder-resnet-22-StreamThread-1-consumer, groupId=_entellect-cbe-builder-resnet-0] Discovered group coordinator sdc-oxygen-dev-cp-kafka-4.sdc-oxygen-dev-cp-kafka-headless.sdc-oxygen-dev:9092 (id: 2147483643 rack: null)
09:55:07.473 [kafka-coordinator-heartbeat-thread | _entellect-cbe-builder-resnet-0] INFO  o.a.k.c.c.i.AbstractCoordinator - [Consumer instanceId=sdc-oxygen-dev-entellect-cbe-builder-resnet-22-1, clientId=sdc-oxygen-dev-entellect-cbe-builder-resnet-22-StreamThread-1-consumer, groupId=_entellect-cbe-builder-resnet-0] Discovered group coordinator sdc-oxygen-dev-cp-kafka-4.sdc-oxygen-dev-cp-kafka-headless.sdc-oxygen-dev:9092 (id: 2147483643 rack: null)
09:55:50.644 [sdc-oxygen-dev-entellect-cbe-builder-resnet-22-StreamThread-1] INFO  o.a.k.s.p.internals.StreamThread - stream-thread [sdc-oxygen-dev-entellect-cbe-builder-resnet-22-StreamThread-1] Processed 30000 total records, ran 0 punctuators, and committed 1 total tasks since the last update
09:56:20.888 [kafka-coordinator-heartbeat-thread | _entellect-cbe-builder-resnet-0] INFO  o.a.k.clients.FetchSessionHandler - [Consumer instanceId=sdc-oxygen-dev-entellect-cbe-builder-resnet-22-1, clientId=sdc-oxygen-dev-entellect-cbe-builder-resnet-22-StreamThread-1-consumer, groupId=_entellect-cbe-builder-resnet-0] Error sending fetch request (sessionId=1490129196, epoch=INITIAL) to node 0:
org.apache.kafka.common.errors.DisconnectException: null
09:56:20.888 [kafka-coordinator-heartbeat-thread | _entellect-cbe-builder-resnet-0] INFO  o.a.k.clients.FetchSessionHandler - [Consumer instanceId=sdc-oxygen-dev-entellect-cbe-builder-resnet-22-1, clientId=sdc-oxygen-dev-entellect-cbe-builder-resnet-22-StreamThread-1-consumer, groupId=_entellect-cbe-builder-resnet-0] Error sending fetch request (sessionId=1666554310, epoch=INITIAL) to node 4:
org.apache.kafka.common.errors.DisconnectException: null
09:56:20.989 [kafka-coordinator-heartbeat-thread | _entellect-cbe-builder-resnet-0] INFO  o.a.k.clients.FetchSessionHandler - [Consumer instanceId=sdc-oxygen-dev-entellect-cbe-builder-resnet-22-1, clientId=sdc-oxygen-dev-entellect-cbe-builder-resnet-22-StreamThread-1-consumer, groupId=_entellect-cbe-builder-resnet-0] Error sending fetch request (sessionId=522549112, epoch=INITIAL) to node 5:
org.apache.kafka.common.errors.DisconnectException: null
09:56:47.135 [sdc-oxygen-dev-entellect-cbe-builder-resnet-22-StreamThread-2] INFO  o.a.k.s.p.internals.StreamThread - stream-thread [sdc-oxygen-dev-entellect-cbe-builder-resnet-22-StreamThread-2] Processed 70000 total records, ran 0 punctuators, and committed 1 total tasks since the last update
09:57:04.873 [kafka-coordinator-heartbeat-thread | _entellect-cbe-builder-resnet-0] INFO  o.a.k.clients.FetchSessionHandler - [Consumer instanceId=sdc-oxygen-dev-entellect-cbe-builder-resnet-22-1, clientId=sdc-oxygen-dev-entellect-cbe-builder-resnet-22-StreamThread-1-consumer, groupId=_entellect-cbe-builder-resnet-0] Error sending fetch request (sessionId=1490129196, epoch=INITIAL) to node 0:
org.apache.kafka.common.errors.DisconnectException: null
09:57:04.873 [kafka-coordinator-heartbeat-thread | _entellect-cbe-builder-resnet-0] INFO  o.a.k.clients.FetchSessionHandler - [Consumer instanceId=sdc-oxygen-dev-entellect-cbe-builder-resnet-22-1, clientId=sdc-oxygen-dev-entellect-cbe-builder-resnet-22-StreamThread-1-consumer, groupId=_entellect-cbe-builder-resnet-0] Error sending fetch request (sessionId=1666554310, epoch=INITIAL) to node 4:
org.apache.kafka.common.errors.DisconnectException: null
09:57:04.973 [kafka-coordinator-heartbeat-thread | _entellect-cbe-builder-resnet-0] INFO  o.a.k.clients.FetchSessionHandler - [Consumer instanceId=sdc-oxygen-dev-entellect-cbe-builder-resnet-22-1, clientId=sdc-oxygen-dev-entellect-cbe-builder-resnet-22-StreamThread-1-consumer, groupId=_entellect-cbe-builder-resnet-0] Error sending fetch request (sessionId=522549112, epoch=INITIAL) to node 5:
org.apache.kafka.common.errors.DisconnectException: null
```

Answer (score 1):

> i already made the heartbeat.interval.ms a bit larger, but this it is
> still happening

It's ineffective for avoiding the exception, As a matter of fact, It's a mechanism for fault-detection; For detecting abnormal situations. If you set a large interval, abnormal condition is detected later and vice versa. In conclusion, if you made it either large or small no difference.

> I have also increased request.timeout.ms shall I also increase
> delivery.timeout.ms, if so why?

I believe they are both independent of each other. for example, If the request is sent to the end-point but it doesn't get any feedback, it doesn't mean the end-point is inactive. Indeed, It happens in reality when end-point is overwhelmed by load and can't feedback as soon as possible. As a result, `request.timeout.ms` should set to a rational value. However, for `delivery.timeout.ms` it should be set to a large number. As stated in official [doc](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#upgrade_2_1_0) about `delivery.timeout.ms`:

> which sets an upper bound on the total time between sending a record
> and receiving acknowledgement from the broker. By default, the
> delivery timeout is set to 2 minutes.

As I mentioned.

> I am trying to understand how things cascade. That is, What happen if
> the heartbeat thread keep trying and then reach delivery.timeout.ms ?
> is that what causes is unavailable or invalid due to cause:
> coordinator unavailable.isDisconnected: true

Yes, heartbeat thread signals to a master node that there is a suspect to failure group after timeout of any type either request or delivery.

> What controls the subsequent retry after that

[Admin](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#adminapi), managing and inspecting topics, brokers, acls, and other Kafka objects